# Ctrl+V images from clipboard into wordpress editor

Tags: plugins

I've been trying to use a plugin that will allow me to copy paste stuff from the mac clipboard (using Command+Shift+4) directly into the wordpress editor. I tried a few (like Image Elevator for Wordpress) but somehow doing a Ctrl+V in the editor did nothing.

Any recommendations to what i could use?

Comment: Dragging and dropping would likely trigger an upload, which is what would be necessary to insert an image. There's no such thing as embedding an image in the post content itself MS Word style, that's not how HTML works

Comment: So right now (using mac) i save an image onto disk using the mac clipping tool. After that, i upload it into the media library and then insert into my post. Can i avoid storing image onto disk and maybe directly paste it into the post (where maybe it automatically gets uploaded to media library and inserts it)?

Comment: No, there isn’t.

Comment: Don't Macs paste with Command+V instead of Ctrl+V? I've been using Image Elevator for years and it works great. Never had any problems with it.

Comment: @nev.m there must be an image to upload, and an image is a file. Either way a file **must** be created

Comment: You may want to try the new Gutenberg editor, currently available as a plugin. They've been working on adding paste-image capabilities. But the others here are correct, there's no way to paste an image into the classic/current editor.